# Define the set of K-Nearest-Neighbors.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation, order-theory

Say i have a set $X=\{x_i|i\in[N]\}$ (where $[N]=\{i\in\mathbf N|0<i\le N\}$) and a metric $d(x,y)$ (distance). $x$ and $y$ could be in euclidean space for example and either be part of $X$ themselves or not.
The set of all neighboring relations between all pairs of points $x$ and $x_i\in X$ has an ordering and can be an "ordered set" (I dont know much about that).

1) How do I define such an ordered set?
2) How would I define the set of $k$ nearest neighbors to a point $x$, lets call it $\mathbf{N}^k(x)$

This set contains points from $X$, namely the first $k$ points with the smallest distance to the point $x$ (including $x$ itself if $x\in X$).
I was thinking to answer question 2) by somehow constructing a set of "first $k$ elements" from the ordered set and go from there. I dont know if this is very elegant though.

Answer (score 0):

The points of a finite metric space can be given
any order as well as the pairs of neighborhoods.
The k nearest points to x is ambiguous.  For example,
with the metric d(x,y) = 1 for all distinct x,y in X, the
set of the 2 nearest points to x is {x,y} for any y /= x.

Whence this problem?  It is jumbled.  Is X embedded in a
space?  If so, what is it?  If X = {1,2,3} is embedded into
R and neighbors can be outside X, then there are no nearest
neighbors of x other than x.

Comment: Yes, all elements of $X$ are supposed to live in the same space as $x$ or $y$, where $d$ is operating on. I see your point about the ambigious order, which makes me think, because I dont actually care about elements if they have the same distance to $x$. However, I also wouldn't know how to define an order for an ordered set if this were true. Further assumptions could be that $x$ is no part of $X$ and $d(x,y)$ is different for all pairs $(x,y)$ iff $x\ne y$.

Comment: Stay within X @BeneIT and use that last assumption.